Jetpack Compose BottomSheetScaffold with LazyColumn rendering too many items and occupying extra space
I am developing an Android app using Jetpack Compose. In my app, I am using the Morfly Advanced Bottom Sheet for convenience, which is very similar to the Material3 BottomSheetScaffold as it is built upon it. Initially, I thought the issue might be a bug in the Morfly library, but after switching to the official Material3 component, the problem persisted.
The issue is that the LazyColumn inside the bottom sheet seems to render more items than it should. It appears to occupy more space than the content should allow. When I run the app, only 5 items are visible on the screen, which is expected. However, when I log scrollState.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo, it shows that 17 items are rendered, even though they are not visible to the user. This over-rendering is leading to performance issues.
What is important for me, along with performance, is that the exact visible items are rendered in the bottom sheet and not more.
I've tried playing around with modifiers and height constraints, but the problem remains. If I set a fixed size for the LazyColumn, the over-rendering issue goes away, but this also prevents the bottom sheet from expanding when necessary.

here is my screen composable:
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun LeagueScreen(viewModel: LeagueScreenViewModel) {
    val scrollState = rememberLazyListState()
    val tops = UtilsKt.getMockTops(20)

    LaunchedEffect(scrollState) {
        snapshotFlow { scrollState.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo }
            .distinctUntilChanged()
            .collect { visibleItems ->
                Utils.log("visibleItemIndices: ${visibleItems.map { it.key }}")
            }
    }

    val scaffoldState = io.morfly.compose.bottomsheet.material3.rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState()

    io.morfly.compose.bottomsheet.material3.BottomSheetScaffold(
        sheetShape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp),
        scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
        sheetContent = {
            LazyColumn(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                state = scrollState
            ) {
                items(count = tops.size) { index ->
                    PeopleOnLeagueItem(
                        item = tops[index],
                        onItemClick = { },
                        modifier = Modifier
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    )
},
 content = {}


Try to set a fixed height for the lazy column. In this case it works?

it works but i loose ability of expanding sheet
